# how to find java JPS in my ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm trying to solve a problem that seems to be the JPS is not available.

how can I find the JPS in my ubuntu?

java installed version is:

```
root@server:~/# java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is this: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/462#issuecomment-30589738

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just go to path :

```
/usr/lib/(installation directory)/jdk1.6.0_33/bin/jps
```

and find your jps, if present , if not then install jdk.

Comment: -bash: cd: /usr/lib/jvm: No such file or directory

Comment: what is you java installation directory ? that refers to jvm.

Comment: `$ which java` says `/usr/bin/java`

Comment: yes then your java directory is java, so follow path: /usr/lib/java/(jdk version)/bin and find jps. there. if not pls list the files present in java folder.

Comment: folder `/usr/lib/java` not exists... I found these `/opt/java/64/jre1.7.0_51/` and `/opt/java/64/jre1.7.0_51/` and `/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_45/` .. is this?

Comment: yes  it is, can you find bin folder and in that jps? but your which java shows /usr/bin/java, it means java is present in that folder only.

Comment: founded JPS in `/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin`, thanks! just one more question: my JRE version is 1.7, and the JPS is in the JDK 1.6... is this a problem? Or it's in the correct versions?

Comment: i dont think these should be different, Where these folder reside, in same folder or different. i think it wont cause any error becs both are nearly same and stable versions. if there is jdk present means no need to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you only have the [JRE](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/Java-Runtime-Environment) installed. You need the [JDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) for `jps`